# An issue with chapterbib (TexPad)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, texpad, chapterbib

I write a report using TexPad. Each chapter has a unique reference list. I mainly use chapterbib and natbib packages to make the lists of reference appear; however, could not manage. That is, the references do not appear at the end of the chapters. Before expressing my trouble here, I searched much to learn the problem. People often refer to the modification of aux files. The issue is I cannot see any aux file in the directory which the Texpad work on. Maybe the problem stems from my script. If you can help me, I would appreciate. The script is as follows;

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }
    \newcounter{qcounter}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{scrextend}
    \usepackage{rotating,booktabs,multirow}
    \usepackage[caption2]{ccaption}
    \doublespacing
    \usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.1}
    \newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \addtokomafont{labelinglabel}{\sffamily}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[a4paper,inner=3cm,outer= 3cm,top=5cm, bottom= 5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib} % for the bibliography
    \usepackage{chapterbib} % for the bibliography
    \usepackage{tabularx}    
    \RequirePackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
    \definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
    \definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
    \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 


\listoffigures

\listoftables

\include{chapters/introduction}

\include{chapters/Literature_Review}

\end{document}
```

This is how the introduction looks like:

```
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Background}

    bla bla \citep{grove1982simultaneous}

    \bibliographystyle{apalike}
    \bibliography{Bib_Files/bibliography}
% I also tried \bibliography{Bib_Files/bibliography.bib}
```

This is the bib-file:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib} *%i also tried \begin{filecontents*}{\bibliography}*

@article{grove1982simultaneous,
  title={Simultaneous tests of many hypotheses in exploratory research.},
  author={Grove, William M and Andreasen, Nancy C},
  journal={Journal of Nervous and Mental Disease},
  year={1982},
  publisher={Lippincott Williams \& Wilkins}
}

\end{filecontents*}
```

Comment: still waiting for your help.

Answer (score 1):

it is already a year ago, but I had the same issue. 
The problem is that TexPad is not compiling the bibtex for each subfile. 
You can fix it by custom buildfiles:
https://www.texpad.com/support/macos/typesetting/custom-typesetting

I solved it build a quick-and-dirty static tpbuild file for my particular document. The file takes bash command, so you could create a more dynamic version:

```
xelatex $TEXPAD_ROOTFILE

bibtex $TEXPAD_ROOTFILE
bibtex 01_Chapter
bibtex 02_Chapter
bibtex 03_Chapter

xelatex $TEXPAD_ROOTFILE
xelatex $TEXPAD_ROOTFILE
```